# Array in side an array list in php form

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I want to build a simple form which collect input value and send email. some input name are array, and I just couldn't get the value from these arrays. Below is the code.

```
$keysToKeep = array('CustomFields[6]', 'email');
$values = array_intersect_key($_POST, array_flip($keysToKeep));
print_r($keysToKeep);
foreach ($values as $name => $value)
{
    $message .= $name . ': ' . $value . PHP_EOL;
}
```

HTML Code:

```
Your name:
<input type="text" name="CustomFields[6]" id="CustomFields_6_337" value="" fid="4" fname="Name" size='64' maxlength='64'>
Your Email Address:
<input type="text" class="email" name="email" fid="e" fname="Email" ftype="Email" reqd="1"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Accessing array values in PHP forms goes like this.

```
$customField = $_POST['CustomFields'][6];
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will allow to step through the $_POST array and collect the data it contains. If any of $_POST array's elements is an array itself another loop is used.

```
//loop collects form data     
foreach($_POST as $key => $field) {
     //checks if data being collected is an array
     //if it is an array another loop is used to collect data            
     if(is_array($field)){
            foreach($field as $subkey => $subfield){
                echo $subfield;
            }
     }
     else{
            echo $field;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks MK.Actually the form is from 3rd party, I can't change the name of the input field.

Comment: Are name and email the only form fields that you have to extract data from?

Comment: No, the form is big, that's why i want to use the loop to catach all the datas.